# asp.net mvc -> Roles.IsUserInRole(username,role)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership

Do we need to add any references or import any namespace for 
Roles.IsUserInRole(username,role) - > is it not giving the right result.

```
<% if(Model.Count < 1)
    {%>
        No User's Add Under You!
    <% } else {
        foreach (var item in Model) { %>
    <tr class="tblheader">
        <th> User Name </th>
        <th> Last Activity      </th>
        <th> Administrator     </th>
        <th> Base User    </th>
        <th> Print User    </th>
        <th> SDI User </th>
        <th> Edit User         </th>
    </tr>
    <% if(Model.Count < 1)
    {%>
        No User's Add Under You!
    <% } else {
        foreach (var item in Model) { %>

<td class="usertd">
            <%if(Roles.IsUserInRole(item.UserName,"Administrator")) { %>
             <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/images/buttons/btn_rnd_save.png" alt="Yes" />
            <% } else { %>
            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/images/buttons/btn_Close.gif" alt="No" />
          <% } %>           
          </td>
            <td class="usertd">
            <%if(Roles.IsUserInRole(item.UserName,"BaseUser")) { %>
             <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/images/buttons/btn_rnd_save.png" alt="Yes" />
            <% } else { %>
            <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Content/images/buttons/btn_Close.gif" alt="No" />
          <% } %>           
          </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported `System.Web.Security`

For more details on this you can check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz1zy88e.aspx

Comment: i already did that 

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Web.ApplicationServices
```

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.ApplicationServices for .NET 4.0

System.Web.Security for .NET 3.5

Comment: The class remained the same, but they moved it to a different dll/namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the RoleManager in web.config, as it is disabled by default.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: I  did every thing mentioned in this link,but still it does the same thing? any thing else i need to look at?

Comment: Have you created an ASP.NET security database?  Or, are you using the Windows Active Directory providers?  Do you have authentication (logging in/out) working?  Have you assigned users to roles?

Comment: I am using the ASP.NET database , one provided by asp.net membership provider. I am able to login and i have about 80 users add in the database and 5 roles created.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a breakpoint at

```
IsUserInRole
```

, is it hit?